# How to find number of rows that are changed between two dataframe in R?

Tags: r, compare, sapply

I have two data frames, which are almost same but they have some values changed in some rows. Now I want to find out what are those changed rows and also if there is additional rows included in second data frame what are those?
Let's name first df as x and second as y.

I have tried using "compare" and "all.equal" but it did not work for me.

x
Alan 20  13
Zayn 21  14

y
Alan 20  13
Zayn 21  15
Rita 18  20

Output :
z
Zayn 21  15
Rita 18  20

Comment: please add some data using `dput()` or so.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package.

Get the rows that are in x and not in y.

```
dplyr::setdiff(x, y)
```

Get the rows that are in y and not in x.

```
dplyr::setdiff(y, x)
```

Comment: this does work. but if the number of rows of both the files are not equal then there comes a error.

Comment: Without a sample of you data or infor about the error you find, I don't know how to solve your issue.